# How to use SHAP KernelExplainer with Tensorflow DNNClassifier

Tags: python, tensorflow

Encounter a question while working on TF canned model with SHAP, for instant DNNClassifier.
What parameter could I use in model since canned DNNClassifier doesn't support predict_proba?

*explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(model, data, link)*

*model : function or iml.Model
User supplied function that takes a matrix of samples (# samples x # features) and computes the output of the model for those samples. The output can be a vector (# samples) or a matrix (# samples x # model outputs).*

```
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[1024, 512, 256],
                                        feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                        model_dir='/tmp/stack/All',
                                        n_classes=2,
                                        optimizer='Adagrad',
                                        config=tf.estimator.RunConfig().replace(save_summary_steps=2)
                                        )

predictions = classifier.predict(input_fn=lambda: eval_input_fn(test_x,
                                                                labels=None,
                                                                batch_size=400),
                                 predict_keys="probability")

explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(predictions, test_x)
```

In short, what it expects in shap.KernelExplainer model parameter? A right thing to replace "predictions" in above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definite answer, but did you have a look at [this notebook](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/notebooks/kernel_explainer/Census%20income%20classification%20with%20Keras.ipynb) provided by the authors? The last section might help you:

````
```
# Here we take the Keras model trained above and explain why it makes different predictions 
# for different individuals. SHAP expects model functions to take a 2D numpy array 
# as input, so we define a wrapper function around the original Keras predict function.


def f(X):
    return regression.predict([X[:,i] for i in range(X.shape[1])]).flatten()

explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(f, X.iloc[:50,:])
```
````